# OpenJPA logging into a separate file in Websphere

Tags: java, logging, websphere, apache-commons, openjpa

I've a problem with OpenJPA logging and Websphere (8).
For a few days I try to redirect the OpenJPA logging information into a separate file (instead of the SystemOut log file). This is what I tried:

1. Changing the persistence.xml with logging information (e.g. ). Though I learned that websphere is ignoring this entry. Can I assume that this is correct?
   http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tejb_loggingwjpa.html tells me the same
   Also the wsjpa.log property did not help.
2. Specifying a handler for openjpa (or openjpa.Runtime, ...) in JSR-47 configuration file does not work either (other configurations worked). What I realized here is that there is actually no openjpa logger in the java logging (java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager().getLoggerNames()). Does that mean that OpenJPA is not logging to a dedicated logger but just writes to SystemOut which is then processed by websphere?
3. I searched through all the different loggers and traces in the websphere console and tried a few, but none of them contained any openjpa logs. Can I assume that there is no other location where openjpa logs to in websphere?

To conclude: It's not working and I cannot use a handler for the openjpa logs because there are no logs generated. OpenJPA in websphere is just printing to the SystemOut which is internally used for the tracing. Does anyone have an idea what to do?

Alternatives would be: 
- Use HPEL
- Script to filter the trace.log

But actually I would rather have a file handler for OpenJPA in Websphere.

Thanks for your help and I can supply you with some more information if you need that.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use application logging system for this purpose based on 3d party logging library for example `logback`.

[`logback`](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/) is very powerful library.